# Convert python hash script to PHP / Call python script from php with variables

Tags: python, php, authentication

another shot. I want to ask you about this script

In python I have this working script

```
 #! /usr/bin/python
 import hashlib
 from crypto.md5crypt import md5crypt
 hashlib.sha1(md5crypt(password.encode('utf-8'), salt.encode('utf-8'))).hexdigest()
```

What this script does is that it create "hashed" password.  I would like to change this script into  PHP script because I need it for logging to website that uses php script

I know its not great solution but I can call the script from php this way

```
  <?php
   $command = escapeshellcmd('/home/python/login.py');
   $output = shell_exec($command);
   echo $output; // this is what I need to login
   ?>
```

This way I can get the hassed password from browser. If is it possible how can I pass two waribale here?

```
 $command = escapeshellcmd('/home/python/login.py $salt_variable $password_variable');
```

where $salt_vriable and $password_variable are previously generated.

I tried to look for the info about it, but python isn't my language and it gives me really hard time. Thanks for any help. If you need better description I can provide it.

Comment: look into Python argparse. Why don't you hash in php?

Comment: "because I need it for logging to website"—you don't need password hashes to log into websites. You need them (a) to store if you have a user database and (b) to verify that a user has give you a valid password. If you pass a hash into a password field you're effectively using the hash as a regular plaintext password. It's pointless.

Comment: It is not my website. I was trying to find the right way to get the password but with no luck. Only the python has worked. I is better for me to have this script, because I am using their API to access some data. When I use password as a word it fails. Only that hased form works.

Comment: "It is not my website"—that's exactly my point. Password hashes have no value to an end user unless the site's security is truly horrendous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import hashlib
import sys
from crypto.md5crypt import md5crypt

assert len(sys.argv) == 3
salt = sys.argv[1]
password = sys.argv[2]

sys.stdout.write(hashlib.sha1(md5crypt(password.encode('utf-8'), salt.encode('utf-8'))).hexdigest())
```

Note the first line in the above code -- you had an extra space and this code.

Your PHP code should be:

```
$escaped_password = escapeshellarg($password_variable);
$escaped_salt = escapeshellarg($salt_variable);
$command = "/home/python/login.py $escaped_salt $escaped_password";
$output = shell_exec($command);
```

You need to escape the password first in case it has, for example, spaces in it. If you just escape the entire command line, it will appear to have extra arguments if the password has spaces in it. And if you escape the arguments, there is then now no need to call `escapeshellcmd`.

Comment: Thx for reply. I tried your script but the python gives me this error. I am not using python3. I hope it doesn't mind that much. When I changed it to python I got this
       
the error points to = near the ner end=''
                                                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I changed the first line and the print statement. It should hopefully now work for Python 2.

Comment: this was quick and great. Thank you. It works now as I wanted. Still the "transformation" into PHP would be great. But now thanks to you I can move forward

Comment: I made one more change because I am not sure whether it was writing out an extra newline at the end of the the encrypted string.

Comment: I put it all in my BIG script and it makes the magic working. Thank you again so much!!!